# How to render the AJAX response in the JSP/HTML element (returned from db)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVdjg.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv1nb.png)How to render a ajax response from db (map) in jsp screen

I am getting response in browser console but not sure how to render it in jsp on the browser screen like a table or any better suggestion

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){

         var problemId = $('#search_data').val();

         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/bugs/" + bugId,
            success: function(data){
                $("#response").html(data);
                console.log('response data',data);
            },
            error : function(err){
                console.log('error',err)
            }

         });
      });
```

JSP

```
<body>
      <div>
         <div>
            <h1>Lookup from Oracle database</h1>
            Click on this <strong><a href="/success.jsp">link</a></strong> to visit home page.
         </div>
         <div>
            <h2>${message}</h2>
            <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Search Category:</td>
               <td>
                  <select name="searchcategories">
                     <option value="-1">-Select Category-</option>
                     <option value="bug">bug</option>
                     <option value="attachment">attachment</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Entity Id:</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="bugId" id="search_data"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search bug no..">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td><button type="button" id="submit_btn" onclick="">Search</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Bug Id:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="bugId"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Prob State Name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="probStateName"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Priority Name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="priorityName"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){


      });
       $('#submit_btn').click(function(){

         var bugId = $('#search_data').val();

         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/bugs/" + bugId,
            success: function(data){
                $("#response").html(data);
                console.log('response data',data);
                 var bugDetails = data;
                 renderDetails(data);
            },
            error : function(err){
                console.log('error',err)
            }

         });
      });

       function renderDetails(data)
       {
           var id = document.getElementById("bugId");
           var name = document.getElementById("probStateName");
           var priority = document.getElementById("priorityName");

           id.innerHTML = data.bugId;
           name.innerHTML = data.probStateName;
           priority.innerHTML = data.priorityName;
       };
   </script>
</html>
```

below is the response object that I see in console that has data fetched from backend. I want to render this ajax response below the search box

[Log] response data (oracle-lookup, line 65)
Object

data: {bugId: 298, stateCode: "2", …}

Object Prototype

Comment: Where is that `probStateName` and `priorityName` fields?

Comment: These are in the data returned in map object from controller. But I don't know how to render in UI(sorry not a front end developer). If you could show which html element to use for renedering.

Comment: Change `renderDetails(data);` to `renderDetails(bugDetails);`

Comment: Check my code, I have change `var id = document.getElementById("problemId");` and `<td><input type="text" id="problemId"  class="form-control">` because there is already a field called `bugId`.

Comment: Yes I am using same, and thats not working(bug maps to problem in my code, no other changes )                                                                                                      var id = document.getElementById("problemId"); and <td><input type="text" id="problemId" class="form-control">

Comment: You are using "input type="text" ".....will it render the ajax response ?

Comment: yes. post the code you are trying now.

Comment: It is same as above, right?

Comment: No, It's not. Check my code.

Comment: Hi Hasitha, I need a placeholder for json response taht is not there in this code, if its working for you could you please share a screenshot.

Comment: Check the update code.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate data to any field from the following code. Probably best to also add a check to see whether the returned values are not empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bugDetails;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit_btn").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

        var bugId = document.getElementById("search_data").value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/bugs/" + bugId,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                bugDetails = data;
                renderDetails(bugDetails);

                alert(data);
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(textStatus);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
    });

    function renderDetails(bugs)
    {
        var id = document.getElementById("problemId");
        var name = document.getElementById("probStateName");
        var priority = document.getElementById("priorityName");

        id.value = bugs.bugId;
        name.value = bugs.probStateName;
        priority.value = bugs.priorityName;
    };
</script>
```

So now your code should be like this,

```
<body>
      <div>
         <div>
            <h1>Lookup from Oracle database</h1>
            Click on this <strong><a href="/success.jsp">link</a></strong> to visit home page.
         </div>
         <div>
            <h2>${message}</h2>
            <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Search Category:</td>
               <td>
                  <select name="searchcategories">
                     <option value="-1">-Select Category-</option>
                     <option value="bug">bug</option>
                     <option value="attachment">attachment</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Entity Id:</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="bugId" id="search_data"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search bug no..">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td><button type="button" id="submit_btn">Search</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Bug Id:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="problemId"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Prob State Name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="probStateName"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Priority Name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="priorityName"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var bugDetails;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit_btn").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

        var bugId = document.getElementById("search_data").value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/bugs/" + bugId,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                bugDetails = data;
                renderDetails(bugDetails);

                alert(data);
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(textStatus);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
    });

    function renderDetails(bugs)
    {
        var id = document.getElementById("problemId");
        var name = document.getElementById("probStateName");
        var priority = document.getElementById("priorityName");

        id.value = bugs.bugId;
        name.value = bugs.probStateName;
        priority.value = bugs.priorityName;
    };
</script>
</html>
```

I have created `Text Fields` to fetch the data coming from `AJAX` call. Make sure you are using these `ids`.

```
            <tr>
               <td>Bug Id:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="problemId"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Prob State Name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="probStateName"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Priority Name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="priorityName"  class="form-control">
               </td>
            </tr>
```

And when data comes from the `AJAX` call it will fetch to above fields using this method,

```
function renderDetails(bugs)
    {
        var id = document.getElementById("problemId");
        var name = document.getElementById("probStateName");
        var priority = document.getElementById("priorityName");

        id.value = bugs.bugId;
        name.value = bugs.probStateName;
        priority.value = bugs.priorityName;
    };
```

So what you need to care about is make sure text field ids are correct.